# Android OpenCV on Motorola devices...

Tags: android

I've been reading that there is a problem using the OpenCV for Android library on Motorola devices. Here is the link to the OpenCV library: http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/OpenCV4Android And here is a link to the issue report: http://code.opencv.org/issues/1244 The issue report lists the target version for the fix to be 2.5 (currently at 2.4). Does anyone have any first hand experience with these issues and any workarounds for the current version of the library? From the OpenCV Google Group there seems to be some discussion about using the "Java Camera" instead of the "OpenCV native" camera. I'm not sure what they mean by this. Thanks for the help! --amb

NOTE:  Posted this on gamedev a few days ago, but got zero replies so far...
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/29801/android-opencv-on-motorola-devices

Comment: Java vs native: OpenCV for Android is mostly the standard OpenCV C++ codebase, reached from the Android JVM via JNI. They are talking about getting images using Java vs. getting images using OpenCV C++, particularly modules/highgui/src/cap_android.cpp. I am looking forward to the resolution of 1244 as well!

Comment: Thank you for the reply...Hopefully this will be resolved shortly.